# Elastic Search connection refused with Docker Compose (connect ECONNREFUSED )

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

There are multiple services that I had been trying to run (redis, front-end, back-end and elastic-search) and I was not able to connect to the elastic search service. I even tried giving a static ip for the service. (The networking part is currently commented out in the docker file attached). I tried changing the images and it still was not working.

When I tested ES locally using `curl localhost:9200/_cat/health` as I have mapped the container port locally it gives me that the cluster is green. I could connect to the other services like redis without issues. As with redis, I am using the service name, `elasticsearch` to connect it to the back-end service. Following is my docker-compose.yml file.

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  arc-external:
    image: arc-external
    build:
      context: ./arc-development-branch/arc-external
    ports:
      - '4201:4201'
    # networks: 
    #   - vpcbr
  redis:
    image: redis:3.2.11-alpine
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    # networks: 
    #   - vpcbr
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:2
    ports:
      - '9200:9200'
      - '9300:9300'   
    environment:
      - node.name=elasticsearch
      - cluster.name=datasearch
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=elasticsearch
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - ./data/elastic:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    # networks: 
    #   vpcbr:
    #     ipv4_address: 10.5.0.4
  api-external:
    image: api-external
    build: .
    ports:
      - '3001:3001'
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - elasticsearch
    # networks: 
    #   - vpcbr

# networks:
#   vpcbr:
#     driver: bridge
#     ipam:
#      config:
#        - subnet: 10.5.0.0/16
#          gateway: 10.5.0.1
```

This is the exact error that I am getting when running docker compose-up

```
api-external_1   | 2021-03-09 20:41:46.3253 - info: Finished setting up log directories
api-external_1   | 2021-03-09 20:41:46.3514 - info: Connection successful to mongodb @ mongodb://10.0.0.44:27017/arc
api-external_1   | 2021-03-09 20:41:46.3764 - info: Connection successful to redis at: host: redis port: 6379
api-external_1   | Elasticsearch ERROR: 2021-03-09T20:41:46Z
api-external_1   |   Error: Request error, retrying
api-external_1   |   HEAD http://elasticsearch:9200/ => connect ECONNREFUSED 172.24.0.4:9200
api-external_1   |       at Log.error (/usr/src/app/api-external/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/log.js:226:56)
api-external_1   |       at checkRespForFailure (/usr/src/app/api-external/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:259:18)
api-external_1   |       at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/api-external/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:164:7)
api-external_1   |       at ClientRequest.wrapper (/usr/src/app/api-external/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4935:19)
api-external_1   |       at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:198:13)
api-external_1   |       at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
api-external_1   |       at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:401:9)
api-external_1   |       at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
api-external_1   |       at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
api-external_1   |       at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
api-external_1   |       at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
api-external_1   |       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
api-external_1   | 
api-external_1   | Elasticsearch WARNING: 2021-03-09T20:41:46Z
api-external_1   |   Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch:9200/
api-external_1   | 
api-external_1   | Elasticsearch WARNING: 2021-03-09T20:41:46Z
api-external_1   |   No living connections
api-external_1   | 
api-external_1   | 2021-03-09 20:41:46.3844 - error: Error: Failed to connect to elasticsearch @ elasticsearch:9200
api-external_1   |     at exports.esClient.ping (/usr/src/app/api-external/dist/setup/elastic-search.js:33:46)
api-external_1   |     at respond (/usr/src/app/api-external/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:327:9)
api-external_1   |     at sendReqWithConnection (/usr/src/app/api-external/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:226:7)
api-external_1   |     at next (/usr/src/app/api-external/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connection_pool.js:214:7)
api-external_1   |     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
api-external_1   | 2021-03-09 20:41:46.3854 - error: Error: No Living connections
api-external_1   |     at sendReqWithConnection (/usr/src/app/api-external/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:226:15)
api-external_1   |     at next (/usr/src/app/api-external/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connection_pool.js:214:7)
api-external_1   |     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
api-external_1   | npm ERR! code ELIFEC
```

Frankly, I searched a lot and were not able to debug it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the answer. The thing stating as depends_on does not wait the services to completely up. Here, `api-external` does get start up as soon as the redis and elasticsearch starts. However, elasticsearch need a bit time to configure everything so restarting the service will do the trick.

More permanent solution is to write a script that would wait until the elasticsearch is up completely before starting the `api-external` service

Comment: Hey, did you find a - better - solution to this? I want to run a script in one container that requires elastic search (another container) to be up running and open to connections - sounds like the issue you had.